# Multiple Columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have lots of columns with the contents of student name, but I need this to be contained in the one column, specifically in the first 'student name' column in 'Problem' sheet column C. I searched this and find a lot of information that points to `CONCATENATE()`, but thats not what I want. I want all the data in Column C, V and W to stack in their correct rows. Any help please?

[Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16mF2ISNO_6BpE8vfUu9URSb-3bISpWQHWgxMkKGxqek/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

So, you could use if() to do this:

Based on your outcome sheet -

```
IF(B1<>"",B1,IF(C1<>"",C1,IF(D1<>"",D1,"error")))
```

See image:
[image]

If you don't want the error message then:

```
IF(B1<>"",B1,IF(C1<>"",C1,IF(D1<>"",D1,"")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You speak of concatenating so use this function:
    =CONCATENATING (B1,C1,D1)
Does this answer your question?